# Getting an error when connecting to an API using HttpClient

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, asp.net-core-webapi

This is a problem on the HttpClientWrapper ,tried connecting to the API endpoint from the device/emulator?

```
string result = _failedResult;
        try
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Set the headers
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                using (HttpResponseMessage responce = httpClient.GetAsync(uri).Result)
                {
                    if (responce.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        result = responce.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var reasonPhrase = responce.ReasonPhrase;
                        result = responce.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        var errormessage = string.Format("Error:{0} {1} for uri :{2} ", reasonPhrase, result, uri.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var t=ex.InnerException;
            result = ex.Message;
        }

        return result;
```

Expecting i need to get phonenumbers list as a JSON format from the server.

Instead I'm getting the following error:

> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused

Comment: Can you please edit the question format. Your question is quite unclear. Please explain the problem in detail.

Comment: check if you need to call with https and not http or the way around.

Comment: It may be due the firewall of the server (where the API is sitting is blocking the request)  DID you try running you api in the browser

Comment: are you trying to call a localhost webapi from emulator?

Comment: when i am calling the api method from the xamarin application in that time i get the error :System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused

Comment: @naveenkumar localhost, or what? I mean the api url

Comment: yes @alaa_sayegh

Comment: Are you calling localhost api? If yes, please make sure your API is running.

Comment: @NaveenKumar, check my answer

Comment: this is the uri="https://localhost:44388/api/Common/getPhonenumbers"

Comment: Is your api service i.e. port 44388 running? Make sure it is running.

Comment: @NaveenKumar, let me know if my answer solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an `Android Emulator` then asking for the localhost web service won't work, because you're looking at the `localhost` of the emulator.

You can fix this as follows:

`Android Emulator` has a magic address `http://10.0.2.2:your_port` that points to `127.0.0.1:your_port` on your host machine. Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html). Because it points to an IP and not localhost, you need to go into your project solution, in .vs folder -> config-> applicationhost.config and change this `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:44388:localhost" />` into , where 44388 is your port. Restart IIS Express and you're good to go.

So use: "http://10.0.2.2:44388/api/Common/getPhonenumbers"

Comment: Am getting this error ...when i am changing the uri:- Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. ---> Java.Security.Cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. ---> Java.Security.Cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.